# Which Ec2 aws instance to use for my project

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I am new to web deployment in aws. I have decided to use a vps on aws for deploying my flask app.
I stumbled upon ec2 but I am confused which instance to use, if my e-commerce website gets aprox. 100,000 hits per month. Is 2gb ram enough with 2 core cpu?

My website details-
An e-commerce website with multiple webpages, mysql database and a decent amount of traffic
Ask me if you want more details. Thank You.

I have tried searching on youtube reading blogs but couldn't find a straight answer.

Comment: Possibly helpful guidance on [Right Sizing](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-optimization/right-sizing/).

Comment: Additional DB information request from present website, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide sizing suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a t3a.small. You can change the instance type later in 5' and get a bigger one if needed.

In your case, I would move the db to Aws RDS. From my point of view, this is the first question to address.

Of course, before deploying the solution you should tune the configuration. For example, when I deploy Laravel projects, nginx and PHP configurations can change the website's performance a lot.